# Rotating feature perpendicular to feature in another layer using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, basic-license-level, rotate

[image]

I am using ArcGIS Desktop basic licence I have created polygons (rectangles) in one layer and i want to move them so that they are exactly perpendicular to a boundary in another layer.

I have been using the rotate tool and 'a' to enter specific angles but it is quite time consuming. I know I could have created the polys using the sketch tool and aligning it perpendicular to the boundary layer.

1. but i wanted them exactly the same size, distance, orientation etc to each other, so i simply copied and pasted.
2. I am trying to avoid restarting. There is quite a lot on here r.e. rotation but not exactly what i need.

Comment: It would be nice to have a picture of what the situation currently is and how you would like it to be. Are you trying to create new polygon rectangles in a feature class or rotate existing rectangles?

Comment: Hello rotate existing rectangles.

Comment: sorry sent to soon, not sure how to post a pic

Comment: Ok pic posted. its simplified i would like the blue rectangle perpendicular to the closest red line above. i almost is but not quite, and I did it with rotate tool - time consuming.

Comment: To do this I would probably write a Python AddIn using ArcPy.

Comment: I'm a twit i meant parallel.....not perpendicular although not sure that matters to the approach